# Test doesn't work on Jenkins (It works on local machine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

When  I run test cases in my local machine it works while when I run the same test case in Jenkins for CI doesn't work because is unable to identify a button.

I used the same gems in Jenkins and in my local machine (capybara (2.4.4),cucumber (1.3.18),cucumber-rails (1.4.2),selenium-webdriver (2.45.0)).

the method click_on "Add new job" return the error  Unable to find link or button "Add new" (Capybara::ElementNotFound).

I already try to use the css below my tantative:
1. find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus', :visible => true) 
2.find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus', :visible => false).set(true)
3. page.find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus').click
But also return me an error unable to see the css under test.
I have inserted sleep time also but it is not the solution.
Have you got any comments/suggestions/feedback ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the tests on your CI server are running *exactly* as you run them? Like it has done all the prerequisite actions like logging in, etc.?

Comment: Yes it is. The prerequisites are the same with the same user.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I still haven't found the solution :\